# javascript variable cannot been redeclared but cannot been accesed, too

Tags: javascript, scope, ts-check

I'm a newcomer in Javascript. I have two files with js code.
file a.js contains

```
const words = ["Alpha", "Bita", "Gama"];
console.log(words);
```

file b.js contains

```
//@ts-check
const words = ["Alpha", "Bita", "Gama"];
console.log(words);
```

Both a.js and b.js are located in folder src under the root
In the root, I also have a jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
       
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

In file b.js, I receive an error "Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'words'."
When I comment out the declaration of words in b.js, I don't receive any error, but when running file b.js, I receive a "ReferenceError: words is not defined".

I know that erasing the `//@ts-check` in b.js will fix the problem, but I cannot understand why type checking produces this behaviour. What is the meaning to keep a variable in scope if you are not allowed to access it?
I use Visual Studio Code and run with node.

Comment: Are you _sure_ this is about JavaScript and not about TypeScript, and is that really `jsconfig.json`, not `tsconfig.json`..?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. The files are as I have described them.